# Swift - Cannot Connect to PHP server

Tags: php, swift, null, connection, option-type

Here is my code:

```
let url = NSURL(string:"path/to/file.php")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
var error: NSError? = nil
let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

let results = NSString(data:reply!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

It gives me the error:

> fatal error: unexpected found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I tried playing around with the ? and ! symbols but couldn't make it work. So there is this issue of how do I handle getting a nil value.

Also, I'm confused as to why this code is getting nil at all since the path to the php file is definitely correct and the php file outputs the correct information when displayed in a webpage.

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM authors"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt as $arr)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {
            echo "$arr[$i]#";
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: "path/to/file.php" is not a valid HTTP URL.

Comment: @MartinR The actual URL is: http://ec2*******.compute-1.amazonaws.com/file.php. Is this not acceptable?

Comment: Does it start with "http://" ?

Comment: Yes it does. stackoverflow makes it into a link when i start with http://

Comment: Ah nevermind I just double checked my code and it turns out I didn't include the http:// at the beginning, thanks for that! However, is there still some way I should be handling the nil value if the connection doesn't work for whatever reason?

Comment: Sure. Each forced unwrapping with "!" or "as!" is a potential crash at runtime. Lookup "optional binding", there are lots of Q&A about it already on SO.